# Authenticate the client

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth

I'm using Google Calander Api Javascript libraries. And for Authentication I'm using OAuth 2.0.

My question is: how can I authenticate a specific client?

For example I want to authenticate the following client: yossi@gmail.com:

```
function load() {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', auth);
}

function auth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': clientId,
        'scope': scopes,
        'immediate': false
    });
} 
function makeRpcRequest() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'resource': resource
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try[This](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#basicsteps) to use google calander API.